Proper response to iMIP `COUNTER` when not supported
I have an iMIP (RFC 6047; sending icalendar files via email) system which supports sending REQUEST and processing incoming REPLY.  However, we get quite a few COUNTER requests from Outlook clients and I'd like to handle them properly.
The RFCs hint at how to do this, but doesn't provide a concrete example.  I think the proper method is to reply with an icalendar with a REQUEST-STATUS indicating a 5.0 error, but I don't know what the rest of the icalendar should look like.  For example, the icalendar is required to have a METHOD, but what should that be?  Should it just be a straight copy of the icalendar we couldn't process with the REQUEST-STATUS inserted?
Should the response be METHOD:DECLINECOUNTER and also include REQUEST-STATUS:5.0;Request not supported;COUNTER?
Since most of these are Outlook, I'd prefer whatever works best with replying back to Outlook that COUNTER is not supported.
